# Drawing with a canvas over an ImageView

Tags: android

I want to create an ImageView and then draw text on top of the ImageView. I also need to be able to modify the text periodically. Currently I've created a custom view that extends ImageView. Then I overwrite onDraw() and use it to draw the text. Only problem then is that when I use my custom ImageView it doesn't draw the image, just the text.

```
public class BoardView extends ImageView
{
    public BoardView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        setImageResource(R.drawable.board);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawText(x.getName(), x.getX(), x.getY(), paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the super.onDraw in your onDraw method before your draw code.

Comment: Haha wow I feel silly that seems so obvious. Thanks so much though!